# How to store a small list, on Android? SharedPreferences VS SQLite VS file

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I have an app that generates objects of a class, let's call it X, that is **Serializable**. I want the user to be able to **occasionally** save or delete objects of X from his/her list of favorites (a list that can go up to 100 objects).

What is the most appropriate way to persistently store the list of favorites?

1. In SharedPreferences, storing the whole list as a JSON String
2. In an SQLite database:-

   1. Storing one item per object, as BLOB's
   2. Storing one item per object, as JSON Strings
3. In a custom file, storing the whole list as a JSON String
4. Some other way?

### My thoughts are:

- Because adding and removing favorites will be occasional, and the list is small, I probably don't need the advantages of a DB when it comes to searching fields in large amounts of data. So I am inclined to maintain a local ArrayList, add and remove items from it, and save it to SharedPreferences (option 1).
- It seems odd to save a key-value pair holding an entire list as a JSON String, I'm afraid I might be unaware of some sort of limitation.

  - Is there a limit to the size of the String I can store in SharedPrefferences?
  - Is it too problematic that I add or remove objects from my local ArrayList and then save the whole list?

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with your first approach because of It's manage easily and need small storage space.